# Sending data to AWS Kinesis stream cross-accounts with Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to send data to a Kinesis stream from 1 AWS account to another account with Lambda.
I tried to use assume-role and my code is:

```
        assumed_role_object = self.sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/cross-account-access",
        RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession"
    )

    credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']

    kinesis_resource = boto3.resource(
        'kinesis',
        aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
    )
    kinesis_resource.put_record(StreamName='StreamName',
                                     Data=encoded,
                                     PartitionKey=partition_key,
                                     ExplicitHashKey='string',
                                     SequenceNumberForOrdering='string'
                                     )
```

and I get this error:

> ResourceNotExistsError: The 'kinesis' resource does not exist.
> The available resources are:
>
> - cloudformation
> - cloudwatch
> - dynamodb
> - ec2
> - glacier
> - iam
> - opsworks
> - s3
> - sns
> - sqs

So I understand that `sts` does not support `kinesis`.
Someone knows a way to send data to `kinesis` cross-account?

Answer (score 1):

This aws document can be referred which demonstrated cross account application writing to kinesis data stream using kinesis client library (java/python) - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/field-notes-how-to-enable-cross-account-access-for-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-using-kinesis-client-library-2-x/